# Check if file exists locally in Adobe Extendscript

Tags: javascript, json, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I try to check for local files (.jpg) using a plain js loop. I get an error that, for example, file `5d3eb1905b243.jpg` does not exists, but actually it does.

Also, I don't understand why the `else` statement ins't working and why `5d3eb1905b243.jpg` isn't replaced with `none.jpg`.

Maybe the path is the problem?

Here's the code:

```js
if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('sharedimage_id')) {
  var imgFile = new File(
    '/Users/student/Desktop/seminar_robobooks/archiv/img/' +
      obj[i].sharedimage_id +
      '.jpg',
  );

  if (imgFile.exists) {
    noStroke(imgFile);
    image(obj[i].sharedimage_id + '.jpg', 56.5, 70.793, 69, 42);
  } else {
    noStroke(imgFile);
    image('none.jpg', 56.5, 70.793, 69, 42);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in a console?

Comment: Where is the code executed?

Comment: If this runs in the browser… you can't simply access or even request arbitrary files on the user's system. That would be a serious security issue.

Comment: I don't see `File` anywhere in the [Basil.js reference](http://basiljs.ch/reference/), and it's not a standard part of JavaScript. Does InDesign provide it? If so, have you checked the documentation for it? I assume you're not trying this in the browser, but if you are, the [`File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) doesn't take a path and you can't access local files from the browser.

Comment: The code runs in InDesign CS6. `File`actually worked on another occasion.

Comment: We can't tell you if your path is a problem or not - we can't see your file structure, or your permissions.

Comment: The path of the images is `/Users/student/Desktop/seminar_robobooks/archiv/img/`, the script is in `/Users/student/Desktop/seminar_robobooks/`. Permissions shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: `obj[i].sharedimage_id` is targeting multiple .json files. The path of the .json files is `loadString("/Users/student/Desktop/seminar_robobooks/archiv/json/"+ a + '.json');`, and this actually works.

Comment: What do you mean "targeting multiple JSON files". It's a variable, so not sure what "target" means in that context? What is the actual content of `obj[i].sharedimage_id` in the example above? And what does any of this have to do with JSON suddenly? I thought you were trying to open a jpg. It's unclear what the connection is to the JSON file. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing enough context to your question.

1. [Basil.js](https://github.com/basiljs/) is a InDesign Javascript/Extendscript library for generative programming. Similar to Processing and P5.js
2. Extendscript is a Adobe flavor of Javascript (Ecmascript 3) with some additions like `File` or `XML`
3. We can't tell if the files on your filesystem exist or the Path is right

**Question:** Which Basil version are you using? v2 (still in Beta)?

Below is a little more boilerplate code to keep discussing and some pointers.

1. the `noStroke` does not get an argument see [this](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/color/nostroke)
2. the file `none.jpg` needs to be in the data dir next to the InDesign Document you are executing against or you need to provide a absolute path See [this](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/image/image)
3. See [this tutorial](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/tutorials/10-adding-images/) on how to handle images

```js
var obj = [
  {
    sharedimage_id: '123456',
  },
  {
    sharedimage_id: '789012',
  },
];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  // the File API test is part of Extendscript
  // https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign10/#File.html
  var imgFile = new File('/absolute/path/to/' + obj[i].sharedimage_id + '.jpg');

  if (imgFile.exists === true) {
    // no stroke does not take an argument
    //https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/color/nostroke
    noStroke();

    image(obj[i].sharedimage_id + '.jpg', 56.5, 70.793, 69, 42);
  } else {
    noStroke();
    // the image needs also a path as the one above 
    // or should be in the data dir nest to the ID doc.
    // ID doc needs to be saved for that
    // https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/image/image
    image('none.jpg', 56.5, 70.793, 69, 42);
  }
}
```

P.S. I'm one of the authors and I'm linking to the current development version of the Reference. The links might break in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. i created a `data` folder and everything worked just fine!

Comment: Great. Happy that it worked out. Are you using the v2 Basil version? Looks like it.

Comment: No, I'm using basil.js 1.0.10

Comment: @VHS I suggest moving on to v2. We fixed a lot of bugs and it actually is pretty stable. You can get the latest v2 here https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/blob/develop/basil.js  You can drop it next to your code and just include it with `// @include './basil.js'`

Comment: Ok, thank you. By the way, I placed a question regarding InDesign scripts here [link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127524/indesign-script-targeting-specific-text-frames), maybe you can help me there?